# Java executor to call external executable only slightly faster

Tags: java, concurrency, runnable, executorservice

I have a Java program that needs to call the same external executable 6 times.  This executable produces an output file and once all 6 runs are complete I "merge" these files together.  I did just have a for-loop where I ran the code, waited for the first run of the external executable to end then I called it again, etc.

I found this highly time consuming, averaging 52.4s for it to run 6 times...  I figured it would be pretty easy to speed up by running the external executable 6 times all at once, especially since they aren't dependent on one another.  I used `ExecutorService` and `Runnable`, etc. to achieve this.

With my current implementation, I shave about ~5s off my time, making it only ~11% faster.

Here is some (simplified) code that explains what I'm doing:

```
private final List<Callable<Object>> tasks = new ArrayList<Callable<Object>>();

....

private void setUpThreadsAndRun() {
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(6);

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        //create the params object
       tasks.add(Executors.callable(new RunThread(params)));
    }

    try {
        executor.invokeAll(tasks);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        //uh-oh
    }

    executor.shutdown();
    System.out.println("Finished all threads!");
}

private class RunThread implements Runnable {
    public RunThread(ModelParams params) {
        this.params = params;
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
         //NOTE: cmdarray is constructed from the params object
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(cmdarray);
         pb.directory(new File(location));
         p = pb.start();
    }
}
```

I'm hoping there is a more efficient way to do this...or maybe I'm "clogging" my computer's resources by trying to run this process 6 times at once.  This process does involve file I/O  and writes files that are about 30mb in size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only time that forking the executable 6 times will earn a performance boost is if you have at least 6 CPU cores and your application is CPU bound -- i.e. mostly doing processor operations.  Since each application writes a 30mb file, it sounds like it is doing a large amount of IO and the applications are IO bound instead -- limited by your hardware's ability to service the IO requests.

To speed up your program, you might try 2 concurrent processes to see if you get an improvement.  However, if you program is IO bound, then you will never get much of a speed improvement by forking multiple copies.

Comment: I did some testing, I changed my code from 6 to 1 and timed it, then went to 2 and the performance benefit was negligible.  So I guess my code is "correct" but my hardware is too slow...thanks for confirming my suspicions, time to CTRL-Z ;)